# Prove. $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I'm a student studying for a test for my real analysis course. I've been given the above question. I'm going to attempt to solve it, if anyone has any tips or tricks to steer me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!

First I fix $\epsilon > 0$ and show for all $n,m >N, |a_n - a_m| < \epsilon $

$$\bigg| \frac{n}{n+1} - \frac{m}{m+1} \bigg|  <\epsilon$$

$$\bigg| \frac{n(m+1)-m(n+1)}{(n+1)(m+1)} \bigg|  <\epsilon$$

$$\bigg| \frac{n(m+1)-m(n+1)}{(n+1)(m+1)} \bigg|  \leq |m+1| +|n+1| \leq |2m|+|2n| <\epsilon$$

$$2m<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies m < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

$$2n<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies n < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$.

Therefore.
$$|2m|+|2n| < \frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have assumed the conclusion. You have to find the appropriate $N$ so that this is true and I do not see you name such an $N$. Also note that if $\epsilon < 1$ then $|m+1| + |n+1| < \epsilon$ is absurd since in general $n \neq m$.

Answer (score 3):

It converges to $1$.  And every convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument does not make sense. You did not come up with a suitable $N$.

$|\frac  n {1+n}-\frac  m {1+m}|= \frac {|n-m|} {(1+n)(1+m)} \leq \frac {|n-m|} {nm} |=|\frac 1n -\frac  1 m| \leq \frac 1n +\frac  1 m <\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$ if $n >\frac 2 {\epsilon} $ and $m >\frac 2 {\epsilon} $. Take any $N> \frac 2 {\epsilon} $.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon>0$.

for any $n,m$,

$$|a_m-a_n|=|a_m-1-(a_n-1)|$$
$$\le \frac{1}{ m+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Take $ N=\lfloor \frac{2}{\epsilon}\rfloor$.

then

$$n,m\ge N \;\;\implies  \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}<2\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$\implies \;\; |a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$$

$\implies (a_n) $ is Cauchy.